# How do I change the icon on click in this example?

Tags: javascript

I've made an element with a button and when you click on it, the second element appears. But I want to change the icon as well when that happens, but I have no clue how to incorporate that into the existing code.

This is my example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRwLeo

I know I can do addClass/removeClass with jQuery, but I'm trying to avoid using it. What do I need to do to accomplish it with JS?

Is it something like:

```
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
```

And how do I add it into the existing code, with FontAwesome icons and their classes? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the output you're getting and the desired output.

Comment: I'm getting nothing because I can't get it to work. :/ The end goal is to have the FontAwesome icon that's an arrow, change into anything else when someone clicks on the button/link. For example, into an X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code pen example you provided, you can add an id to your `<i>` tag (`<i id="icon">`) and include this code in the `toggleDiv` method to change the icon.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="togglediv('item')">
  button <i id="icon" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

JS:

```
function togglediv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.visibility = div.style.visibility == "hidden" ? "hidden" : "visible";
    div.style.opacity = div.style.opacity == "0" ? "1" : "0";

    var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-right');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-left');
}
```

---

---

***Edit:*** Fix for issues where div does not show up on the first click.

CSS:

```
.right-side {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  transition:visibility 0.3s linear,opacity 0.3s linear;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.hide-div {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden; 
}

.show-div {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="right-side hide-div" id="item">
  text goes here
  <p>text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here</p>
  <p>text goes here</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.classList.toggle('hide-div');
div.classList.toggle('show-div');
```

Comment: This approach is simple and it works great! Thank you, I'm accepting it as correct as soon as SO lets me!
One thing I'm wondering about - why is it that in my code, the button never works on the first try? When you click on it, it doesn't show the div on the first try, but on the second only?

Comment: You are changing the visibility and opacity styles manually. Instead create 2 new CSS classes with these values and toggle them, the same way we are doing with the icon. I will update the answer with this fix.

Comment: Got it, changed it and it works now. Thanks, you were really helpful!!

Comment: No problem. Updated the answer with custom classes to show/hide the second div. There are much better ways to do this though. Other examples found here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Answer (score -1):

First, your exemple is not HTML valid.

Best way to reach a goal is to make little steps, I propose you to start with that (put it on codepen).

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="test()">button</a>
```

**JS**

```
function test() { console.log('You clicked me'); }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain what do you mean by it's not HTML valid?

Comment: You cannot put a link into another link